# Determining whether a group is cyclic by finding its subgroups

Tags: group-theory

In my text book we are given the question: 'Is $\mathbb{Z}^*_{15}$ cyclic?'

And in the answers we are given: 'We find that in this group, the subgroups generated by the elements are {1}, {1, 4}, {1, 11}, {1, 14}, {1, 2, 4, 8}, and {1, 7, 4, 13}. Since none of these is equal to the whole group, we deduce that it is not cyclic.'

I understand that every subgroup must contain the identity {1} and that $4^2 mod15$ gives the identity giving the group {1, 4}. We can also do the same thing with {1, 11}, {1, 14} but i don't understand how they got {1, 2, 4, 8} and {1, 7, 4, 13}.

Answer (score 1):

$\{1,2,4,8\}$ simply is the subgroup generated by $2$ because $2^2=4$ mod $15$, $2^3=8$ mod $15$ and then $2^4 = 16 = 1$ mod $15$. Similarly, $\{1, 7, 4, 13\}$ is the subgroup generated by $7$.

Comment: How come they didnt include the subgroup generated by other numbers in the group e.g. 3?

Comment: $3$ is not in the group.

Comment: Surely the group is the integers 1 - 14 inclusive? mod 15

Comment: No, the group consists in the $\varphi (15)=8$ numbers (or residues, actually)  relatively prime to $15$.  For instance,  $3$ and $15$ are not coprime.

Comment: Oh thank you, that explains a lot